# scala actors and persistence context

Tags: scala, jpa

Is it possible to inject a persistence context into a scala actor every time it acts?  I have a dual Java/Scala spring application, and I am using spring annotations to markup my Java services and methods as transactional.  I'd like to use similar functionality within my scala actors.  That is, the actor should operate within a single transaction every time it responds to a message.  Has anyone tried something similar or are there examples out there of this kind of thing?

Answer (score 7):

Why not encapsulate the persistent access via a `Dao` `trait` which is injected into the actor itself. This way you can have a persistence actor which is decoupled from the persistence mechanism itself:

```
class DaoActor(val dao: Dao) extends Actor {

   def act() = {
     loop {
       react {
         case SaveTrade(trade) => dao.save(trade)
         case ReadTrades(date) => dao.lookup(date)           }
     }
   }
}
```

What's more, your `Dao` could be coded in Java, so you can add the `@Transactional` annotation there.

Comment: I think that I will have to use some form of the above solution.  I will need a service that I can instantiate as part of the Spring context marked as `@Transactional` so that Spring properly proxies the object.  Then, my actor will be injected with a reference to the service and will call into the service to perform the actual work.  This solution is fine and will work but I was hoping to have a more Scala centric solution.

Comment: Can't you decorate your Scala with @Transactional? Scala does support annotations, albeit non-nested.

Comment: I'm not 100% on this but I'm not sure scala quite supports the same level of annotations (e.g. nested) as Java. That said, a plain `Transactional` declaration with isolation levels etc defined may well work